# Will the growth of calculation speed of personal computer end after that of classical computer will end?

Tags: quantum-computing

According to the answer of Andrew Yeats in this [link](https://www.quora.com/When-will-I-be-able-to-buy-a-PC-that-has-a-quantum-processor), quantum computer's advantage is so narrow that personal computer is not likely to benefit from the development of quantum computer. I think this is understandable, so will the growth of calculation speed of personal computer end after that of classical computer will end (in 2020~2025)? If so, is there any candidate of new computation model which will replace personal computer in the future?

Comment: I find the question unclear.  1. That's not a very good summary of Andrew Yeats' statement.  To understand his argument, one has to click through the link, which makes this question not very self-contained.  I suggest editing the question to make it clearer what exactly is the argument that you want a response to.  I *think* Yeats argument is that quantum computers can only solve certain problems fast, and it's not clear whether ordinary users will care much about those problems.  2. What does Yeats' argument have to do with your questions? (cont.)

Comment: I can't tell why you think the growth of the speed of personal computers would end in 2020-2025, nor why you think this has anything to do with quantum computers.  3. Please ask only one question per question.  4. What research have you done?

Comment: History or legend, Bill Gates  supposedly said in 1981 "640K ought to be enough for anybody.", and certainly acted as if he believed it. This kind of predictions are often a waste of time, though thinking prospectively may be useful. I doubt anyone knows when quantum computing will effectively solve large scale problems. Will PCs continue to exist as such, or be replaced by pervasive computing. Few people expected the Internet in the seventies, when some were already working on it. The only likely thing is that whatever happens will probably be unexpected.